# Do standard headphones work with the XBox 360 controller?

Tags: xbox-360

I want to listen to my games, but not disturb anyone.  I don't have a pair of headphones, so I want to double-check before I go get some: do they work with the XBox 360 controller?

Answer (score 3):

You can use standard headphones to listen to game sound, but not by connecting them to the controller. You would need to use a television with a headphone jack, and then jack into that.

Some fancier headphones will come with an optical hookup, which can be connected to back of the Xbox itself. I have a Turtle Beach gaming headset. It connects to the controller for the voice communications, and the Xbox for the game audio.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The xbox 360 controller has a 2.5mm jack but it is used for voice communications only, no game audio. Headsets that carry both game and voice audio require you to plug directly into the TV or the xbox to get the game audio.

Answer (score -2):

The 360 controller does not have a 3.5mm headphone jack it is a smaller one i think it is a 2.5mm

Answer (score -3):

I've ordered a little gadet on Wish.com
It has a the same 2.5mm jack with pins on one side, and then two 3.5mm jacks for earphones as well as mic. So yes, it can be done with such an adapter. Otherwise, there is an Xbox 360 headphone set with the exact aux cable needed for the remote, with mic attached.   Image included of the adapter.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtEOJ.jpg)